# Javascript isn't working in Firefox/IE but works in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

For some reason my nav collapse function isn't working in Firefox/IE but works in Chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#header').data('size','big');
    });

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var $nav = $('#header');
        if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
                $('#logo').fadeOut(300);
                $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                    height:'95px'
                }, 600);
            }
        } else {
            if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
                $('#logo').fadeIn(300);
                $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                    height:'185px'
                }, 600);
            }  
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any ideas? I'm thinking it's a syntax error.

You can see the live example in the navigation at http://medialimes.com

Comment: You're getting errors in the console. You should probably check that.

Comment: Also in Firefox the body element never seems to scroll, so its "scrollTop" is always zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `$(window).scrollTop()` instead of `$('body').scrollTop()`. This should work on both Chrome and Firefox/IE.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you try to set

```
$('#header').data('size','big')
```

doesn actually set the data variable properly.

Try setting it using the attr method.

```
$(#header).attr('size','big');
```